# State is not showing after changing order status - Woocomerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a store "WordPress - Woocommerce" ( i have also another store at the same cPanel and I'm not facing this issue so it is not hosting issue).

when I receive the order, I get all the address entries correctly
The Field "State" is a mandatory field with a dropdown list at the checkout page.

after I receive the order, (from the mobile browser only) if I change the order status to on-hold or any other status, the state gets deleted from the address, see images below.

BEFORE (no issues here):

- Address details after receiving an order from Woocommerce Dashboard
  [click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fu96.png)
- Database entries in Wopa_postmeta for the order before change status
  [click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6Kxp.png)

AFTER I changed the order status from the mobile (here is the issue):

- address details changed and the state got deleted [click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kH9Es.png)
- then here from the database Wopa_postmeta after changing the status
  [click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbEMe.png)

as you can see two entries got deleted
_Shipping_State and _billing_state

Please note that this issue is only when I use the dashboard from a mobile browser, but from the computer, I can change the status without any issues.

So anybody has any solutions for this?
I have disabled all plugins and the issue is the same, WP is updated to the latest version.

Thank you

Comment: This issue might be related to cookies. Did you check to make sure that the mobile browser accepts cookies, or if javascript is actually enabled?

Comment: yes, it is enabled and accepting, tried from iOS - Android mobiles, different browser like safari - chrome and the same issue